# How to externalize application.properties to an external filesystem location in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, tomcat, deployment, spring-boot

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource(value = { "file:/Users/Documents/workspace/application.properties" })

public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

In this case it gives while deploying:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency:
```

Not able to find the correct way to externalize the application properties file

I tried autowiring environment variable which is correctly loaded but then I need to manually define all the beans

```
@Bean 
public JdbcTemplate dataSource() {
    String driverClassName = env
            .getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName");
    String dsUrl = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
    String username = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
    String password = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");
    //DataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource(new driverClassName, dsUrl, username, password);
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    return jdbc;

}
```

This deploys without throwing error but not responding.

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying a WAR to Tomcat, then you need to define a context XML as described here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

For example, you would typically define $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml if you have http://localhost:8080/my-app/.

The file would then look like this:

```
<Context docBase='path/to/my-app/my-app.war'>
   <Environment name='app_config_dir' value='path/to/my-app/' type='java.lang.String'/>
</Context>
```

In your code, implement ApplicationContextAware and override setApplicationContext. Here is an example:

```
public class Setup implements ApplicationContextAware {

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)  throws BeansException {
    log.info("Set application context. App Config Property: {}",applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("app_config_dir"));
  }
}
```

You can now load the properties file from `app_config_dir`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define it by using `@PropertySource` annotation. You should just use `spring.config.location` property to set your `application.properties` location. That property can be set up for example in command line:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.location=/Users/Documents/workspace/
```

Comment: I am actually packaging that into a .war and deploying it in tomcat server. I could not think of passing the command line argument other than export
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dspring.config.location=file:/usr/local/myapp/application.properties" which my architect pointed out changing a webserver level variable, for which we need to restart the server! Need to pass that as some existing environment variable and the filename need to be inside the war build!

Comment: You don't have to use environment variables. You can use anything that is known about in the Spring `Environment` (`ServletContext` init params for instance if you want it *inside* the archive, or JNDI properties if you want it external).

Answer (score 0):

You can define an environment variable called `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` and give it a value that can be a folder (which should end in `/`) or a file. In any case the location should pe prefixed with `file:`:

```
SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION = file:C:/workspace/application.properties
```

or

```
SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION = file:C:/workspace/
```

More about this [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Comment: It has the problem now all the apps deployed on the server will scan through that file or folder for properties, although it works for the deployed war! Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PropertySource` too because it is useful when you are deploying application as war file to tomcat.

`@PropertySource` is not working because you are missing `@Configuration` annotation. As per the [Spring-Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) documentation, `@PropertySource` annotations should be present on your `@Configuration` classes.

Following works

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource(value = { "file:/Users/Documents/workspace/application.properties" })

public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

You can also load multiple properties file. For ex:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties", "file:/Users/overriding.propertis"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Note that the order of the declared files is important. If the same key is defined in two or more files, the value associated with the key in the last declared file will override any previous value(s).